# ZXING - Handling of "barcode not found" and "impossible to decode barcode"

Tags: java, barcode, zxing

I'm using google library ZXING in order to decode a Code39 Barcode, and I want to handle in a different way the "barcode not found" case and the "impossible to decode barcode" case: is it possible?

Thanks so much

Comment: You should really say what you want to do -- 'different way' doesn't specify anything.

Comment: I want to show a popup message like "No barcode found in page x" or "Impossibile to decode barcode in page y"

Comment: When would you be able to conclude there is no barcode there?

Comment: I use this line to decode a barcode:
Result result = new Code39Reader().decode(bitmap);.
Maybe it could be useful to throw two different exceptions (BarcodeNotFound and ImpossibleToDecode) instead of the existing one (NotFoundException), which groups both cases.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't tell you there is no barcode there. You can't really know that. It may be there but failed to decode on this frame, but might decode on the next frame.

Comment: Ok. My point was: using ZXING is it possible to understand if the failure was on the research part or on the decode one? And, if it is not possible, may it be an improvment of future releases?

Comment: Yes, look for NotFoundException vs ChecksumException or FormatException. The latter two don't guarantee there's a barcode there but it means it really looked like one was there, just wasn't fully read.

Comment: Thanks, if you post that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different exceptions are thrown depending on the apparent nature of the failure to decode.

The most common is `NotFoundException`, which means it didn't see anything that begins to look like the outline of a barcode. There may or may not be a barcode there; it just didn't see it.

`FormatException` and `ChecksumException` are thrown if the barcode seems to have a bad format. That means it found something that looks like a barcode but failed during parsing. That usually happens because it almost read it correctly but not quite. That is, this indicates more strongly that there is some barcode there.